# Why does eclipse close by itself while running?

Tags: eclipse

It's been happening lately for some unknown reason.I have the latest version of Eclipse ADT (25 Sept 2014) and it just shuts off while I'm working. Any ideas?

Comment: check the eclipse error logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start Eclipse from a terminal to see the standard output. Chances are that the Java VM runs into a problem because of SWT which can crash the VM. Note: If you're using Windows, you may have to use `java.exe` instead of `javaw.exe` to get output.

Also look into the Error Log. Eclipse has a view for that or look into the file `.../workspace/.metadata/.log` The file might contain an error message.

If you find an error in either the console or the error log, let us know and we might be able to help.

Comment: I'd be glad to. Unfortunately I can't find error log. Sorry I'm new at this. I've tried:
 
- Window -> Show View -> Error Log (for Java folder)
 
- I don't have a .metadata folder... could it be named another way?

Also I feel the need to say that sometimes it doesn't close at all. But today, for example, it has closed twice after about 15 minute sessions

Comment: The `.metadata` folder is hidden. Check your OS's documentation how to display hidden folders. And did you start Eclipse from inside a terminal / command prompt?

Comment: ok I found the folders and looked the problems up. There was a compability problem with some software I had downloaded. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue could also be because of the JVM that was chosen for the project.